# Using relational expression in yii findOne()

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

In Yii2, to use **findOne()** to grab a single record with exact match is simple. For example:

```
// find the first customer whose age is 30 and whose status is 1
$customer = Customer::findOne(['age' => 30, 'status' => 1]);
```

But what if you want to find one where `age` is **less than** 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findOne` will not directly handle this.

You can do it as follows:

```
$customer = Customer::find()->andWhere(['>', 'age', 30])->andWhere(['status' => 1])->one();
```

Answer (score 2):

`findOne` method will automatically call the one() method and return an ActiveRecord instance. So you can use the following:

```
$customer = Customer::find('age<:age AND status=:status',[':age' => 30, ':status' => 1])->one();
```

which is equivalent to `findOne()`

For more details refer to this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findOne%28%29-detail)

Comment: I might have selected this answer but it did not include the second parameter 'status => 1'

Comment: Updated the answer. It might be help for someone.